# jenkins trigger build on another slave

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Consider this scenario -> I have 2 Jenkins slave Slave1 and Slave2, running jobs DeployJob1 and DeployJob2  respectively.

Here is my requirement -> whenever DeployJob1 finishes successfully I want to trigger DeployJob2.

Now, the problem is that we are on 2 different slaves. Is there a plugin which can help with this?

Note: I have already tried Parameterized Trigger Plugin but that only helps in case second job is on same slave.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to achieve this with the Parameterized Remote Trigger Plugin by pointing it at your master and tying DeployJob2 to Slave2 in its configuration (if it's not already)

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Remote+Trigger+Plugin